# Having trouble setting value for my file upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to set my default value (value form database) in the input field for the image upload input. I have tried `set_value()` and it does not seem to work. I am able to get all other fields other than the image upload input.

I am stuck and would appreciate some help if possible, thank you.

My view:

```
echo form_label('Upload Recipe Image:', 'userfile');    
$valueArray = array(        
    'name' => 'userfile',           
    'value' => $image           
    );      
echo form_upload($valueArray);
```

controller func:

```
function update_recipe($id) {
        $this->load->model('upload_model');
        $recipe = $this->upload_model->get_recipe($id);
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '';
        $config['max_width']  = '600';
        $config['max_height']  = '';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors('<p>', '</p>');
            $data['user_info'] = $this->model_users->view_user('users')->result();
            $data['recipes'] = $this->recipe_model->get_recipes();
            $this->load->view('includes/header');
            $this->load->view('includes/navigation-header', $data);
            $this->load->view('error', $data);
            $this->load->view('includes/bottom-nav');
            $this->load->view('includes/footer');
        } else {
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();
            $data = array(
                'id'  => $this->input->post('recipe_id'),
                'title' => strtolower($this->input->post('recipe_name')),
                'description' => $this->input->post('recipe_description'),
                'stars' => $this->input->post('rating'),
                'directions' => $this->input->post('recipe_directions'),
                'genre' => $this->input->post('recipe_genre'),
                'posted' =>  date('Y-m-d'),
                'image' => $image_data['file_name'],
                'imagePath' => $image_data['full_path']
            );
            $this->upload_model->update_recipe_form($id, $data);
            redirect('addRecipe/recipes');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked in your comment:

> The problem is if they want to change the title and not the image the
>   database will update the title but will replace the image with a blank
>   field. How would I get around this?

Assuming that your update_recipe_form function is equal to this (from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271498/how-to-upload-an-image-plus-content-with-one-submit-to-database-using-codeignite)):

```
function update_recipe_form($id, $data){
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('recipes', $data);
    return true;
}
```

Based on this description of `$this->db->update()` function:

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update

if you **exclude some fields from input array**, those values will not be part of generated SQL.

Solution: try to check if those values are empty:

```
$image_data['file_name'], $image_data['full_path']
```

If empty, do not include them in your `$data` array, so you will not overwrite existing DB value with empty one.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, can't believe i did not think of that. good idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can not do that.

Your code is fine, if you inspect your HTML, you will see that *value* is set in your input element, but that is **not allowed for security reasons**, so it is ignored.

Imagine that someone sets dynamically value in your input to *c:\passwords.txt* and then submits form via javascript. Steeling files would be too easy.

Comment: A +1 for this, spot on.

Comment: So if i have a page that allows the user to change there info. I have set all the values of my inputs with values pulled from the database so that if they only want to change the title they don't have to fill out all the other information all over gain. the problem is if they want to change the title and not the image the database will update the title but will replace the image with a blank field. How would i get around this?

Comment: Show us your update logic, I am sure there is a place where some if condition can handle this.

Comment: I added the update func in controller. let me know if you need my model func too. thanks